# SO Careers Error: "An error has occurred when validating your changes"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Whenever I try to edit my e-mail address on the StackOverflow Careers site, I get the following error message:

An error has occurred when validating your changes

I'm currently using IE 9 but I've tried running the site in IE 8 compatibility and the error still comes up.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Comment: Can you reproduce this in IE8? We don't support beta browsers until they are released. We'll take a look, regardless.

Comment: @Jeff: I can reproduce this in FF. It's probably a server-side error of some kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report, everything should be better now.